# php class and method exception

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the public function "should create a virtual machine" with validation,

```
public function deployVirtualMachine($serviceOfferingId, $templateId, $zoneId, $account = "", $diskOfferingId = "") {

        if (empty($serviceOfferingId)) {
            throw new CloudStackClientException(sprintf(MISSING_ARGUMENT_MSG, "serviceOfferingId"), MISSING_ARGUMENT);
        }

        if (empty($templateId)) {
            throw new CloudStackClientException(sprintf(MISSING_ARGUMENT_MSG, "templateId"), MISSING_ARGUMENT);
        }

        if (empty($zoneId)) {
            throw new CloudStackClientException(sprintf(MISSING_ARGUMENT_MSG, "zoneId"), MISSING_ARGUMENT);
        }

        return $this->request("deployVirtualMachine", array(
            'serviceofferingid' => $serviceOfferingId,
            'templateid' => $templateId,
            'zoneid' => $zoneId,
            'account' => $account,
            'diskofferingid' => $diskOfferingId,
            'displayname' => $displayName,
    }
```

I'm trying to call this function, but I keep getting exception " $templateId" is missing. but I'm pretty sure its defined here in my array.

```
  $params = array(

           $serviceOfferingId => '85d06496-bb75-41fb-9358-4ab919e03fe4',
            $templateId => 'c0989cf6-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f',
           $zoneId => '7cd483ab-5aad-458b-b5e1-0e270310f41c',
           $name => 'srv11'
 );


echo $cloudstack->deployVirtualMachine($params);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only passing 1 parameter, an array.

Try this instead:

```
$cloudstack->deployVirtualMachine('85d06496-bb75-41fb-9358-4ab919e03fe4', 'c0989cf6-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f', '7cd483ab-5aad-458b-b5e1-0e270310f41c', 'srv11');
```

Your method is expecting 5 parameters (3 obligatory, 2 optional). `$params` is being received as `$serviceOfferingId`.

Either pass in the values individually, or change the signature of the method to accept a single parameter.

For example:

```
public function deployVirtualMachine($params) {

    if (!isset($params['serviceOfferingId'])) {
        throw new CloudStackClientException(sprintf(MISSING_ARGUMENT_MSG, "serviceOfferingId"), MISSING_ARGUMENT);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

---

One more thing, by using `$serviceOfferingId` as an array key, you're saying that the key should be the value of variable `$serviceOfferingId`. It doesn't seem that that's what you want. Use a string instead; `'serviceOfferingId'`.

```
$serviceOfferingId = 'foo';

$params = array(
    $serviceOfferingId => 'bar'
);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

What you want is:

```
$params = array(
    'serviceOfferingId' => 'bar'
);
```

Which would produce:

```
Array
(
    [serviceOfferingId] => bar
)
```

Comment: Hey Ayman, I'm getting "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Your method expects 5 single parameters of type string, in the method invocation you pass one single parameter of type array - what do you expect?

call it this way:

```
 echo $cloudstack->deployVirtualMachine('85d06496-bb75-41fb-9358-4ab919e03fe4',
           'c0989cf6-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f',
               '7cd483ab-5aad-458b-b5e1-0e270310f41c',
                  null,
                   'srv11' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more weird solution would be, to pass the array `$params` into a [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
      public $deployVirtualMachine = function ()
      {
          ....
```

Params Array (according to Aymans answer)

```
      $serviceOfferingId = 0,
      $templateId = 1;
      $zoneId = 2;
      $name = 3;

      $params = array(
        $serviceOfferingId => '85d06496-bb75-41fb-9358-4ab919e03fe4',
        $templateId => 'c0989cf6-2da5-11e4-a846-726c7bbb864f',
        $zoneId => '7cd483ab-5aad-458b-b5e1-0e270310f41c',
        $name => 'srv11'
      );
```

and then:

```
      call_user_func_array ( 'deployVirtualMachine ', $params );
```

That would pass the array, but renders as more or less unreadable code  :/